# How to solve the leaks when allocating the NSMutableArray in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I am getting leaks in Master view controller of iPhone.

When I call this method, I am inserting them into `filteredListCount` array, because when I search I need to show the list from `filteredListCount` array otherwise `customerArray`.

This functionality is working fine but I am getting leaks in the method below at allocation: `filteredListCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: [customerArray count]];`

This is the first view controller of my application, I am showing the list and I am also allowing to search from a list.

```
- (void)parser:(CustomerListLibXmlParser *)parser addCustomerObject:(Customer *)customerObj1
{

 [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
 [customerArray addObject:customerObj1];
 filteredListCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: [customerArray count]];
 [filteredListCount addObjectsFromArray: customerArray];
 [theTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)parser:(CustomerListLibXmlParser *)parser encounteredError:(NSError *)error
{

}
- (void)parserFinished:(CustomerListLibXmlParser *)parser
{
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
 self.title=@"Customers";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This functionality is working fine but
>   I am getting leaks in the method below
>   at allocation: filteredListCount =
>   [[NSMutableArray alloc]
>   initWithCapacity: [customerArray
>   count]];

There's no garbage collection on the iphone. If filteredListCount is already pointing to a block of memory that's been allocated, and you assign something else to it, that block will continue to exist.

Empty out filteredListCount first.

```
if(filteredListCount){
  [filteredListCount release];
  filteredListCount = nil;
}
// now you're sure filteredListCount is empty
filteredListCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: [customerArray count]];
```

Or, just use a retain property instead.

Comment: If filteredList is a property, make sure to use the `self.filteredList` notation, otherwise it won't call the synthesized accessor method and the array won't be retained.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent memory leak when allocate the array you could check if it exists already. Additionally autorelease it. That is the same to allocate TableViewCell pattern:

```
if(filteredListCount == nil){
    filteredListCount = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[customerArray count]] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not valid approach when using ARC

Answer (score 0):

when, where and how are customerArray and filteredListCount declared ?

IF filteredListCount is a property, use self.filteredListCount=.... to properly release any previous memory. You may also want to do [filteredListCount removeAllObjects]

Its also not clear that you have any dealloc's in your code (which is obviously a leak).